# How to access a controller method from view in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to do something like this in CodeIgniter:

Controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

    public function user($user) {
        return $user;
    }
}
```

View (home):

```
Hi <?php echo user('User') ?> // call a controller method
```

How can i do this?

Comment: why you want to call this in view ?

Comment: Why don't you pass the value along with view.

Comment: because i want to pass some info from view to controller and return the result

Comment: @Uchiha how to do this?

Comment: pass value through controller. 
$data['id'] = $this->user();
$this->load->view('view_file', $data);

Comment: @user1048123 please check the update?

Comment: From where you were getting that value `$user` within that function

Comment: I suggest to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get it is , returning it from the **routes.php** , 
Like `$route['user'] = "home/user";` And this will execute the `user` method from the **home** controller.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm new in CodeIgniter. how to access $route['user'] in view?